# Swift: UILabel.text value shows nil value

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsdictionary, swift4.1

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I have created a custom cell. The cell has a label to display project name. After assigned value to the label, it shows nil value when print. so that label could not display in the table view.

```
let cell = self.LeadsListTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"LeadsID", for: indexPath) as! LeadsCell

    if let leadsDict: NSDictionary = self.leadsArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
    {
       cell.project_title?.text = (leadsDict.object(forKey: "project_title") as! String)
    }
```

This way i used to display the value of the label

```
po print(cell.project_title?.text) (or) print(cell.project_title?.text)
```

Comment: Where you are doing this ? not related : Don't use `NSDictionary`

Comment: Did u reload your tableview?

Comment: As mentioned, if it shows nil while printing the value, how can that be assigned to the cell.project_title?.text.? Are you sure you are getting the data.?

Comment: Is the label outlet connected in the custom cell? By the way: This is Swift, why do you use the ugly *objective-c-ish* Foundation collection types without type information. Use native Swift `Dictionary` (`[String:Any]`). And according to the naming convention variable names are supposed to be *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*.

Comment: Yes I am getting data from the dictionary @Abhirajsinh

Comment: I guess it should be : leadsDict.value(forKey: "project_title") as! String, Try implementing this

Comment: What i have to use instead of the NSDictionary? @Prashant

Comment: add this array value `leadsArray` in your question

Comment: I tried value (forkey:"project_title"), object (forkey:"poject_title" and straight forward method also@a.masri

Answer (score 1):

If the print statement returns nil, that could only mean cell.project_title is nil, since neither cell nor .text are optionals.  Ensure that you initialize the .project_title property before you try setting its .text property.

Answer (score 0):

@A.Yesuvin

put this line above your optional binding (if let) statement

```
cell.project_title?.text = "test_text"
```

If then when you print `print(cell.project_title?.text)` and it's "test_text", then you know you're not allowed to do this : `self.leadsArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary`

If that was the case then try do what @vadian said and use native Swift Dictionary ([String:Any]).

If the code in the if statement actually runs, then double check if the key "project_title" is actually in the dictionary.

If thats the case, then ...well, fix it.

Also just a hint: Continue to use 'optional binding' instead of force unwrapping/ force cast cause you will eventually run into errors doing this: `(leadsDict.object(forKey: "project_title") as! String`
For all we know, This might just be where the "error/nil" lays.